# How to list all of my installed fastlane plugins?

Tags: fastlane

I am looking for a command (or parameter) to list all of plugins that are installed in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for a simple list, but of course viewing the Gemfile to see what is installed is a solution.

```
less Gemfile.lock
```

and, of course, the plugins file

```
less fastlane/Pluginfile
```